# Split file by pages including background

Tags: vba, visio

tl;dr Is there an efficient way using VBA to split a multipage Visio file into different files per foreground page and including a background page?

A simpler version of this question (excluding the background page) has been asked several times over the years, and each time the answer is to use [Paul Heber's Visio Super Utilities](https://unmanagedvisio.com/products/vsu/). I'm sure this tool is wonderful, but unfortunately I can't use it due to company restrictions.

I have a file with ~200 pages, all utilizing the same background template to easily modify common elements. Loading the whole file is unwieldy for daily use, and only a few of the pages are needed by an individual user. I'd like to split it into individual files for convenience and security.

I've come up with 2 approaches for this. I don't have access to Visio on my home machine, so I'll just explain the processes:

1. Set an `UndoScope` to delete every page except the ones I'm interested in. Save, then undo the operation and repeat. This means there will be a 200ish page undo operation repeated 200ish times. I haven't done any testing, but I bet this is a performance nightmare and prone to errors.
2. Open a new instance of Visio and copy individual pages to it. Loop through pages once to find the background (if unknown), transfer it. Loop again to transfer each foreground, save as new file, then delete the page. This seems better but requires a method for transferring pages. I'm not aware of a simple way to do that while preserving layer/protection settings.

I'm hoping there's some 3rd highly efficient solution that I'm unaware of. In a perfect world, it'd be included in `Document.SaveAsEx`. In a less perfect world, it'd be some kind of `Page.ExcludeDuringSave` flag I could set. Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: Now the super utilities can run without admin rights (do not require admin permissions to install). Maybe that could help with your company restrictions.

Comment: Nikolay, I can look into it but they've had a strict "No add-ons" policy. We can't even develop our own add-ons :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just built a completely online solution for this for fun :) It splits the Visio file on the XML level (i.e. works without Visio installed) right in the browser, by removing extra unrelated pages.

Here: https://webtools.unmanagedvisio.com/splitpages

You are welcome to try it out, and send me any feedback. The size of the file may be an issue, or maybe not. I've tried with 2Mb file, looks fine. Also, I have not checked what happens if you have formulas in shapes on one page referring to another page, those formulas will be broken most probably (#ref)

The solution is completely [open source](https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioWebTools/blob/master/azure_function/SplitPages.cs)

Comment: I'm marking this as an answer because it's super cool and probably will work for anyone who has a similar problem! Does this tool allow for a background page to also be transferred in the split?

Comment: Yes, it should handle the background properly. But you could check, of course. The background processing is here: https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioWebTools/blob/470a1d6f799016cf8f9da23314dbc528dbcd9035/azure_function/SplitPages.cs#L37

Comment: I'll have to study this, as it's a bit over my head currently. Unfortunately, I can't utilize your service (or C# for that matter) since my company's security is so tight. I have access to VBA/VBS and that's it. Hopefully I can adapt something to do this in one of those languages because it seems way faster than opening every file!

Comment: I see. But you can use stackoverflow, right? So you have access to the internet, and if the site was running locally (without sending anything anywhere), but just doing the conversion directly in the browser, would that work for you? I mean, if you could even turn off the network for example, when doing the conversion? I'm thinking of moving that over to webassembly, that can run completely in the browser without internet.

Comment: @Vince did it actually (migration to wasm), now the files are not even sent anywhere (will not leave your browser).

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help (I've referenced many of your posts over the years). Unfortunately, I still don't think this will satisfy our (ridiculous) security protocol. A bit of feedback though: Is the DocumentSheet preserved here? I have shapes that set DocumentSheet cells to modify the background page.

Comment: Yes. It just deletes pages, and then saves what's left after deletion. But anyway, doing it with webassembly was fun. Thank you for the idea. Now it's basically as safe as running a script in a sandbox on your machine. Or even on a disconnected machine :D You can try it with some "test" file, not necesserily your working file. It will not be sent anywhere.